# Optimization where the output has constraints

Tags: optimization, constraints

I am working on solving a black box optimization problem where the constraints are applicable on the outcome. Example, my function is pertaining to cost and min customer demand % is the constraint applicable as an constraint on cost.

The issue here is not knowing the internals of function which does not allow me to constrain my decision variables.

Is there a way to implement this using Evolutionary optimizers (Genetic Algo)?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, please suggest libraries or packages that could help with this

Comment: You can always add extra fitness multipliers such as penalty that change with powers of some parameters or powers of outcome. So just return a*fitness from fitness function where a is a continuous function depending on the distance from constraint.